# How to center row of uneven columns with images in them using bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I center a row of images that have an uneven column count e.g when I use the following code (I need to have the images butt up next to each other thats why I have a `.no-padding` class):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 no-padding">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="" />    
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 no-padding">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="" />    
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 no-padding">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="" />    
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/ifusion/pen/RPmMVY?editors=110)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find **[codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JdqLvp?editors=110)**

```
.no-padding {
    padding: 0;
}
.col-md-3{
    float:none;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 -2px;
    padding:0;
}
.tac{
    text-align:center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row tac">
        <div class="col-md-3 no-padding">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="" />    
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 no-padding">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="" />    
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 no-padding">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="" />    
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this : http://www.minimit.com/demos/bootstrap-3-responsive-centered-columns

```
.row-centered {
    text-align:center;
}
.col-centered {
    display:inline-block;
    float:none;
    /* reset the text-align */
    text-align:left;
    /* inline-block space fix */
    margin-right:-4px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put `display: inline-block; float: none;` for each `.row > div`, and `text-align: center;` for `.container > .row`

```css
.row {
  float: none;
  text-align: center;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.col-md-3 {
  width: 30%;
}
.row .no-padding {
  display: inline-block;
}
.no-padding {
  border: 1px solid green;
  background-color: #ddd;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 no-padding">
      <!-- <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="" /> -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 no-padding">
      <!-- <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="" /> -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 no-padding">
      <!-- <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="" /> -->
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 no-padding">
      <!-- <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="" /> -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 no-padding">
      <!-- <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="" /> -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```